# Wait until popover is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) and I was wondering how I can wait until a popover is destroyed before showing another element?

Here's the popover destroy call:

```
$('.first').popover('destroy');
```

I've tried doing the following, but it doesn't seem to actually make it to the second call:

```
$('.first').popover('destroy', function() {
    $('.second').popover('show');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?  It waits for the popover to be hidden, not necessarily destroyed.  There is no built in bootstrap event for destruction.

```
$('.first').on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
   $('.second').popover('show');
});
$('.first').popover('destroy');
```

Comment: I was thinking of using a timeout, but I thought there was a different way. Thanks though. :)